# Second cURL is not working, the destination is a servlet and is not working

Tags: php, curl, geocode

```
 <?php
```

in this part I provide a latitude a longitude to reverse geocode.

```
 $ch = curl_init("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.784268,-98.393555&sensor=false");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 $return = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $geoOutput = json_decode($return, true);

 $data = current($geoOutput);
 echo $data;
```

After that I want to pass the content to a servlet but for example purposes I embedded the street and zipcode.
The generated url is like the following, but if you run the url will not happen anything in curl. But if you copy paste the code in the browser will succed.

```
  $urlse="http://136.145.116.30:8080/AccidentDetailsInserter?latitude=18.209&longitude=-67.139&frontal_damage=1&left_damage=1&right_damage=0&back_damage=0&smoke_detected=0&flipped=0&maxforce=7&roll=0&pitch=0&yaw=0&device_id=47&street=Calle Caobos&city= MayagÃ¼ez&state=PR&zip= 00680";

echo $urlse;

     $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 5;
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$urlse);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $data;
```

here the output is blank

```
    ?>
```

I tried to write to specify the port to 8080 but nothing.

Comment: "Not working" is a very bad description of a problem. For example, one could argue that your question is not working at all and as the FAQ makes us believe, not working questions should be removed from the site. I hope yours won't, and if you improve it, there is a chance that this won't get closed.

Comment: Also, if your problem is with the second CURL, why do you paste so much code? I remove everything but the second CURL form your question, so it's more clear about which code your problem is.

Comment: What does the handle/var '$ch' evaluate to prior to curl_exec()?

Comment: I'm not sure id I understand the question but the first curl_exec() its because I want to reverse geocode some coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second URL contains spaces and other unescaped characters that should be urlencoded. If you paste it in the browser the browser fixes that for you. CURL doesn't.

instead of `street=Calle Caobos` or other such parameters, you should send `street=Calle%20Caobos`. just use `urlencode()` on all parameters you are building.

Edit: there were a few things missing here, here is some working code:

```
$urlse="http://136.145.116.30/AccidentDetailsInserter?latitude=18.209&longitude=-67.139&frontal_damage=1&left_damage=1&right_damage=0&back_damage=0&smoke_detected=0&flipped=0&maxforce=7&roll=0&pitch=1&yaw=0&device_id=47&street=CalleCaobos&city=SanJuan&state=PR&zip=00926";
echo $urlse;

     $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 10;
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$urlse);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $data;
```

Comment: can you post the new url you are trying to send?

Comment: 136.145.116.30%3A8080%2FAccidentDetailsInserter%3Flatitude%3D18.209%26longitude%3D-67.139%26frontal_damage%3D1%26left_damage%3D1%26right_damage%3D0%26back_damage%3D0%26smoke_detected%3D0%26flipped%3D0%26maxforce%3D7%26roll%3D0%26pitch%3D0%26yaw%3D0%26device_id%3D47%26street%3DCalle+Caobos%26city%3D+Mayag%C3%BCez%26state%3DPR%26zip%3D+00680

Comment: no, you are now escaping the entire URL. you should escape the parameters, not the whole url. something like: `$url = 'http://domain.com/?param1='.urlencode($param1).'&param2='.urlencode($param2);` etc

Comment: I tried to put the url without spaces and not special characters and It did not work with curl.

Comment: if you post the url you are now trying to send I can have a look

Comment: **http://136.145.116.30:8080/AccidentDetailsInserter?latitude=18.209&longitude=-67.139&frontal_damage=1&left_damage=1&right_damage=0&back_damage=0&smoke_detected=0&flipped=0&maxforce=7&roll=0&pitch=1&yaw=0&device_id=47&street=CalleCaobos&city=SanJuan&state=PR&zip=00926** this is the url that won't work with curl even the format its ok, correct me if I'm wrong. thank you

Comment: ok, I played with it a bit and tweaked the curl params so it will work. see my edited answer.

Comment: sorry for spamming you during my tests :)